# PHP PDO Rollback no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, poo, mvc, pdo

Hola estoy intentando ejecutar un Rollback de PDO en una funcion donde involucro varias tablas y hay varios insert y updates.

Estoy trabajando con MVC y POO.

Quizas tengo algo mal en mi estructura, si es asi podrian decirme donde esta el problema por favor?

Este es mi "Modelo de Conexion" donde ejecuto los Query's y hago la conexion a la BD

```
<?php   

class conexion{
    public $conexion;
    function __construct(){
        require "./config/param_conexion.php";
        $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;port=$port",$user,$pw);          
    }
    public function beginTransaction(){         
        try{                
            $begin = $this->conexion->beginTransaction();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function Commit(){           
        try{
            $this->conexion->commit();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function Rollback(){         
        try{
            $this->conexion->rollback();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function Query($query){          
        try{
            if($this->conexion){

                $resultado = $this->conexion->query($query);                    
                return $resultado;                  

            }else{                  
                return false;
                return $this->conexion->errorInfo();
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }           

    }           
    function __destruct(){
        $this->conexion = null;
    }   
}
```

Este es mi Controlador el cual llama a su modelo:

```
<?php

define('PATH_JSON_CARGO_DESCARGO',"./json/cargo_descargo_mv.json");

class con_cargo_descargo extends mod_cargo_descargo{
    public function UltimoConsecutivo(){

        $resultado = parent::Select_LastDoc();
        $datos = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $datos['documento'] = $datos['documento'] + 1;
        $datos['documento'] = str_pad($datos['documento'],10, '0' ,STR_PAD_LEFT);           

        print json_encode($datos);

    }
    public function Guardar(){

        if( !empty($_POST['tipo_documento']) ){

            if( !empty($_POST['concepto']) ){

                if( !empty( $_POST['tipo_cargo_descargo']) ){

                    //Optengo los productos adicionados en el archivo json
                    $array = array();
                    if(file_exists(PATH_JSON_CARGO_DESCARGO)){
                        $array = file_get_contents(PATH_JSON_CARGO_DESCARGO);
                        $array = json_decode($array,true);
                    }

                    $total = count($array);

                    if($total > 0){

                        //Obtengo el ID y el CONSECUTIVO del ultimo documento
                        $query_LastDoc = $this->Select_LastDoc();
                        $datos_LastDoc = $query_LastDoc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                        //Obtengo la Serie del tipo de documento
                        Require_Controller('tipo_documentos');
                        $obj_tipo_doc = new con_tipo_documentos();
                        $datos_tipo_doc = $obj_tipo_doc->ConsultarJson($_POST['tipo_documento']);
                        $GLOBALS['serie'] = $datos_tipo_doc->serie;

                        if(empty($datos_LastDoc['documento'] )){
                            $datos_LastDoc['documento'] = 0;
                            $datos_LastDoc['id_cargo_descargo'] = 1;
                        }else{
                            $datos_LastDoc['id_cargo_descargo'] = $datos_LastDoc['id_cargo_descargo']+1;
                        }

                        $consecutivo = $datos_LastDoc['documento'] + 1;
                        $consecutivo = str_pad($consecutivo,10,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

                        $GLOBALS['id_cargo_descargo'] = $datos_LastDoc['id_cargo_descargo'];
                        $GLOBALS['documento'] = $consecutivo;

                        parent::beginTransaction();

                        $resultado_ti = parent::Insert_ti();
                        if($resultado_ti){

                            $resultado_mv = parent::Insert_mv($array);
                            if($resultado_mv){

                                //Registramos las existencias
                                Require_Controller('existencias');
                                $obj_existencias = new con_existencias();
                                $resultado_exist = $obj_existencias->Guardar($array);

                                if($resultado_exist){

                                    //Registramos los datos en el KARDEX
                                    Require_Controller('kardex');
                                    $obj_kardex = new con_kardex();
                                    $resultado_kardex = $obj_kardex->Guardar($array);               

                                    if($resultado_kardex){
                                        parent::Rollback();
                                        //$file = file_put_contents(PATH_JSON_CARGO_DESCARGO,'');
                                        print $GLOBALS['msj_successDatProc'];
                                    }else{
                                        parent::Rollback();
                                        print "error|Error al registrar kardex";
                                    }

                                }else{
                                    parent::Rollback();
                                    print "error|Error al registrar existencias";
                                }

                            }else{
                                parent::Rollback();
                                print "error|Error al registrar detalles del documento";
                            }

                        }else{
                            parent::Rollback();
                            print "error|Error al registrar documento";
                        }

                    }else{
                        print "info|Indique los productos a Cargar o Descargar";
                    }

                }else{
                    print "info|Indique un tipo de Cargo/Descargo";
                }

            }else{
                print "info|Indique un concepto";
            }

        }else{
            print "info|Indique el tipo de documento y el concepto del mismo";
        }

    }


}
```

y por ultimo este es su respectivo Modelo el cual tiene como padre al modelo de Conexion.

```
<?php   

class mod_cargo_descargo extends conexion{
    public $table_ti = 'cargo_descargo_ti';
    public $table_mv = 'cargo_descargo_mv';
    public function Select_LastDoc(){

        $query = "
            SELECT 
            id_cargo_descargo,
            documento 
            FROM ".$this->table_ti."
            ORDER BY documento DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ";

        $resultado = parent::Query($query);

        return $resultado;

    }
    public function Insert_ti(){

        @session_start();

        $query = "
            INSERT INTO ".$this->table_ti."
            (
                id_cargo_descargo,
                id_tipo_documento,
                serie,
                documento,
                registrado_por,
                concepto,
                fecha_registro,
                id_tipo_cargo_descargo,
                id_usuario
            )
            VALUES
            (
                '".$GLOBALS['id_cargo_descargo']."',
                '".$_POST['tipo_documento']."',
                '".$GLOBALS['serie']."',
                '".$GLOBALS['documento']."',
                '".$_POST['responsable_cargo_descargo']."',
                '".$_POST['concepto']."',
                '".$_POST['fecha_cargo_descargo']."',
                '".$_POST['tipo_cargo_descargo']."',
                '".$_SESSION['id_usuario']."'
            )
        ";

        $resultado = parent::Query($query);
        return $resultado;

    }
    public function Insert_mv($array){

        $query = "
            INSERT INTO ".$this->table_mv."
            (
                id_cargo_descargo,
                id_articulo,
                id_almacen,
                cargo_descargo,
                cantidad,
                costo_nuevo,
                ubicacion,
                fechayhora
            )
            VALUES
        ";

        $x=0;
        $total = count($array);         

        while($x < $total){
            $query .= "
                (
                    '".$GLOBALS['id_cargo_descargo']."',
                    '".$array[$x]['id_articulo']."',
                    '".$array[$x]['almacen']."',
                    '".$array[$x]['sumaresta']."',
                    '".$array[$x]['cantidad']."',
                    '".$array[$x]['costo_nuevo']."',
                    '".$array[$x]['ubicacion']."',
                    '".$array[$x]['fechayhora']."'
                )
            ";

            $x++;

            if($x < $total){
                $query .= ",";
            }

        }

        $resultado = parent::Query($query);         
        return $resultado;

    }
}
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que si ven el Metodo GUARDAR en mi controlador, estoy haciendo un Require de otros 2 controladores, todos mis controladores tienen la misma estructura, tienen su modelo y cada modelo tiene como padre el archivo de Conexion.

El ROLLBACK es efectivo solo con los INSERT y UPDATES que ejecuto con los metodos que pertenecen al mismo controlador, pero los INSERT y UPDATES de esos 2 controladores de los cuales estoy haciendo REQUIRE no funciona el ROLLBACK.

Es decir que el ROLLBACK no me esta funcionando con funciones que sean externas al controlador donde me encuentro.

Espero haberme explicado...

Comment: Podrías indicar los nombres de las clases en vez de simplemente "controlador", a fin de hacer más seguible tu consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Iniciemos con algo de concepto.

En principio, las transacciones de base de datos, generalmente funcionan a nivel de conexión.

Un servidor puede atender multiples conexiones y realizar exitosamente, de manera aislada, operaciones en cada una de ellas.  Esto incluye, como es de esperarse, las típicas operaciones `insert`, `update`, `delete` y también las instrucciones de control de transacción y las transacciones mismas.

Una aplicación puede establecer multiples conexiones de base de datos y para cada conexión, las operaciones que realice se harán de manera aislada a otras conexiones que la misma aplicación mantenga.

## Ahora si, vamos a tu problema.

El inconveniente reside en que cada modelo, al extender la clase `conexion` está estableciendo una nueva conexión al servidor, y es en esta conexión dónde realiza sus operaciones.

Si quieres que las operaciones de los modelos, en conjunto, sean atómicas (es decir, se haga todo o nada sin importar de que modelo vienen, mi recomendación es que compartas una única conexión entre todos los modelos.

En otras palabras, no extiendas en cada uno a la clase `conexion`, sino que en cada modelo puedes almacenar una referencia a una conexión común entre todos los modelos.

Así, todas las operaciones que realices estarán en realidad contenidas en una sola transacción y podrás hacer un `commit`/`rollback` que las abarque a todas.

Comment: Hermano tienes toda la razon, acabo de hacer los cambios y funciono! Mil Gracias de antemano!!